# Suggested edits: Giving feedback to editor

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, editing, suggested-edits

Reviewing suggested edits, I sometimes come across 'weird' edits, minor changes or real bad editings which change answers (regardless whether they are useful or not).

Apart from

- Approving
- Editing
- Rejecting
- Skipping

I would like to leave some feedback (a comment editor line would do) to the person who caused the suggested editing, if necessary only, however, especially if an edit has to be rejected or edited, why this occurs.

Of course, I could leave an `@USERJOHNDOE` comment somewhere, but this would not be connected to the edit under examination.

Do you think this would be useful in general? Perhaps, it needs an message system for users...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is already partly provided when *rejecting* a suggested edit:

[image]

You are provided with a number of canned responses, including a custom message where you can "clearly explain why you are rejecting the edit":

[image]

Here is [an example of a rejected edit I made](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/41987) displaying a custom message<sup>*</sup>:

[image]

---

The suggester of the edit can review their suggestions by clicking on the activity tab in their profile, and filtering on suggestions:

[image]

---

I would agree that a message in your inbox pointing you to the suggested edit item would be a good idea. It could be considered similar to an announcement of your achievements (awarding of badges) in your inbox.

<sub><sup>*</sup>If only we could draw awesome freehand arrows as well...</sub>

Comment: Well, this is good to know, since none of my previous editings (i.e. before immediate-editing-privilege) were rejected (as far as I know) I did not get such a feedback, so I did not know of this kind of feedback!