# New button on 'Suggested edits' review

Tags: discussion, review-page, suggested-edits, new-features

I came across the new (???) `Reject and Edit` button on the 'Suggested edits' review:

[image]

I have (sorry!) multiple questions on that.

- When was it introduced?
- Is it TeX.SX - only?
- Who used `Reject and Edit` so far?
- Is there some feedback possibility to the user making the suggested edit, as I (and perhaps others too) requested (e.g. have a look on a previous question of mine:  [Suggested edits: Giving feedback to editor](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4441/suggested-edits-giving-feedback-to-editor))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. This was introduced on [September 5th, 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214543/168244).
2. This is [live across the entire Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227991/168244).
3. I've used it once. The motivation for providing this options stems from the ease with which certain insignificant edits are considered helpful when the moderation requires additional edits. That is, when someone makes an edit that the moderator (anyone with the [edit privilege](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)) feels is insufficient, the default "This edit was helpful" used to be pre-selected. So, if nothing was done by the moderator, the edit was considered helpful (scoring the editor +2 rep).

   It was felt that there should be a default "This edit was not helpful, yet a larger edit is in order" option, bringing forth the "Reject and Edit" button we see today. Click on the "[Improve edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239157/168244)" (also new, as of 2014-09-10) option to consider it both helpful and requiring more edit-worthy juice.
4. No. For this you should follow the "Reject" option, where you can provide the editor with some feedback (either a canned or manual response).

---

The above changes to the Suggested Edits review is accompanied with the following additions:

- 2014-09-08: "Too minor" [was removed from the suggested edits reject reasons list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238039/168244).